# How do I convert the following dataframe into a particular format?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have timeseries data in the following format:

```
df.columns= ['Timestamp','Parameter','Value']
```

Here, the column 'Parameter' has repeating characters for every 5 minutes and once the parameter changes the timestamp starts repeating for another parameter. A small sample of the data looks like this:

```
{'Timestamp': {0: '2019-01-01 06:00:00+00:00',
  1: '2019-01-01 06:05:00+00:00',
  2: '2019-01-01 06:10:00+00:00',
  3: '2019-01-01 06:15:00+00:00',
  4: '2019-01-01 06:20:00+00:00',
  5: '2019-01-01 06:25:00+00:00',
  6: '2019-01-01 06:30:00+00:00',
  7: '2019-01-01 06:00:00+00:00',
  8: '2019-01-01 06:05:00+00:00',
  9: '2019-01-01 06:10:00+00:00',
  10: '2019-01-01 06:15:00+00:00',
  11: '2019-01-01 06:20:00+00:00',
  12: '2019-01-01 06:25:00+00:00',
  13: '2019-01-01 06:30:00+00:00',
  14: '2019-01-01 06:00:00+00:00',
  15: '2019-01-01 06:05:00+00:00',
  16: '2019-01-01 06:10:00+00:00',
  17: '2019-01-01 06:15:00+00:00',
  18: '2019-01-01 06:20:00+00:00',
  19: '2019-01-01 06:25:00+00:00',
  20: '2019-01-01 06:30:00+00:00',
  21: '2019-01-01 06:00:00+00:00',
  22: '2019-01-01 06:05:00+00:00',
  23: '2019-01-01 06:10:00+00:00',
  24: '2019-01-01 06:15:00+00:00',
  25: '2019-01-01 06:20:00+00:00',
  26: '2019-01-01 06:25:00+00:00',
  27: '2019-01-01 06:30:00+00:00'},
 'Parameter': {0: 'A',
  1: 'A',
  2: 'A',
  3: 'A',
  4: 'A',
  5: 'A',
  6: 'A',
  7: 'B',
  8: 'B',
  9: 'B',
  10: 'B',
  11: 'B',
  12: 'B',
  13: 'B',
  14: 'C',
  15: 'C',
  16: 'C',
  17: 'C',
  18: 'C',
  19: 'C',
  20: 'C',
  21: 'D',
  22: 'D',
  23: 'D',
  24: 'D',
  25: 'D',
  26: 'D',
  27: 'D'},
 'Value': {0: 1,
  1: 2,
  2: 3,
  3: 4,
  4: 5,
  5: 6,
  6: 7,
  7: 3,
  8: 4,
  9: 1,
  10: 2,
  11: 5,
  12: 8,
  13: 9,
  14: 2,
  15: 4,
  16: 5,
  17: 5,
  18: 3,
  19: 4,
  20: 9,
  21: 1,
  22: 4,
  23: 7,
  24: 2,
  25: 2,
  26: 3,
  27: 1}}
```

I want to change the data in the following format to apply my algorithm:

```
df.columns=['Timestamp','A','B','C','D']
```

I have manually prepared a dataframe to show how it should look:

```
{'timestamp': {0: '2019-01-01 06:00:00+00:00',
  1: '2019-01-01 06:05:00+00:00',
  2: '2019-01-01 06:10:00+00:00',
  3: '2019-01-01 06:15:00+00:00',
  4: '2019-01-01 06:20:00+00:00',
  5: '2019-01-01 06:25:00+00:00',
  6: '2019-01-01 06:30:00+00:00'},
 'A': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7},
 'B': {0: 3, 1: 4, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 5, 5: 8, 6: 9},
 'C': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 5, 4: 3, 5: 4, 6: 9},
 'D': {0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 7, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 1}}
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df.pivot('Timestamp', 'Parameter', 'Value')
```

Output:

```
Parameter                  A  B  C  D
Timestamp                            
2019-01-01 06:00:00+00:00  1  3  2  1
2019-01-01 06:05:00+00:00  2  4  4  4
2019-01-01 06:10:00+00:00  3  1  5  7
2019-01-01 06:15:00+00:00  4  2  5  2
2019-01-01 06:20:00+00:00  5  5  3  2
2019-01-01 06:25:00+00:00  6  8  4  3
2019-01-01 06:30:00+00:00  7  9  9  1
```

Comment: Can this be converted back to the previous format after adding a few more columns?

Comment: Yes, many ways. `df.stack().reset_index()`, `df.reset_index().melt('timestamp')`.